# Code generated with eclipse cdt much faster than in command line

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I have the following question. I've done a program in C++ using OpenCV. I used Eclipse CDT as an IDE with g++ 4.4 compiler. When I compile the program in command line the binary is about two times bigger and much slower than that done with eclipse. In both cases I use dynamic linking (at least I think so) and I use no special options. What can be the reason of this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look the optimization option that Eclipse is using too compile your program.

For example, the -Os option tells GCC to reduce the size as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was -O3 option. I should have checked this, but I have only looked at the command to invoke linker, not the individual files compilation commands. Anyway, until now I didn't realize that the optimization options can have such great impact on the binary effect.

Comment: glad to help ;) Be just aware that sometimes -O3 produce bigger and slower code than -O2, too many optimization isn't always good.